# Python Scripting - How can I launch a subprocess and pipe the stdout of that process to the stdout of a Python script

Tags: bash, python-3.x, scripting

I am writing a Python script that will help me submit homework assignments. What I want to do is pass the login credentials I have stored in a file to a submission script, after which I will hand over to the user for further input. I have come up with the shell command, `cat login_credentials.txt /dev/stdin | python3 submit_hw0.py`. I am almost finished, I just don't know how to execute the shell command `cat login_credentials.txt /dev/stdin | python3 submit_hw0.py`, where submit_hw0.py is replaced by an arbitrary Python file I have stored in a variable named `submission_script`. Also, I have tried to say:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cat login_credentials.txt /d")
```

However, python3 just closes with no output.

Any help would be appreciated,
Kind regards, Kabelo Moiloa.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the Popen class of subprocess module ([link](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)). You can pass stdin and stdout parameters to it. That should solve your problems.